# Spark/Yarn - Connection error RetryingBlockFetcher trying to fetch blocks from random port

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to set up spark on yarn on AWS machines. My spark.driver.port is 32975. I see the below error in the yarn container logs . It is trying to connect to master resource manager port 35653. I am not sure what block is it trying to fetch from port 35653. Could someone help

Spark command

> spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi $SPARK_HOME/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar 10

Hadoop version: 3.x
spark version: 2.4.4

> 2019-12-01 19:09:54,590 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks 
>   java.io.IOException: Connecting to xyz.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:35653 timed out (120000 ms)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:243)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:114)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:124)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:98)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:757)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:162)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:151)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:231)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:211)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1326)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:207)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:84)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use EMR?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if hadoop/yarn in working.
You should start hadoop first and then check if hadoop is running or not just by doing jps in the terminal.

```
hadoop start-all.sh
jps
```

Comment: Each time this port keeps changing  . So i doubt if it has anything to do with any hadoop process being down

Comment: Are you running this on a cluster or in standalone mode?

Comment: The job is submitted to yarn cluster . Deploy mode is client

Comment: Have to tried setting the spark driver port ?
spark-submit --master yarn-client --conf spark.driver.port=xxxxx

Comment: Ensure that HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster. These configs are used to write to HDFS and connect to the YARN ResourceManager. The configuration contained in this directory will be distributed to the YARN cluster so that all containers used by the application use the same configuration. If the configuration references Java system properties or environment variables not managed by YARN, they should also be set in the Spark application’s configuration. Apart from this there should not be any prob.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203444/discussion-between-sambhav-kumar-and-balaji-v).